# On (a) bended knee (s)

Tags: phrase-meaning

> ...,you should be thanking me **on bended knee!** You would have been
> well served if he'd killed you!

My research :
Now if he meant to say that literally, he should have said "on **a** bended knee".
Again we know that if a person is showing reverence, he would be on his both knees.
So I think it should have been "on bended **knees**"?

1. On bended knee?
2. On **a** bended knee?
3. On bended **knees**?

Comment: I would think "on a bended knee" is weird, as if you'd need to get a knee from somewhere first. I'm guessing "on bended knee" is an archaic idiom like "on foot". The plural obviously means you bend both knees, whereas if you only bend one, you end up in a classical marriage proposal position.

Comment: But here I don't think that would be the case, he'd be bending on both knees. Are both of them interchangeable as in both can mean one knees bended and both knees bended?

Comment: I am so confused as to its more literal sense. Some dictionaries cites "on bended knee" as "on knee bent" and some  "one or both". I am confused.

Comment: _On bended knee_ is one of those fossilised phrases that have remained part of the language (nowadays we would say _bent_, not _bended_). I've been unable to trace its origin - it doesn't seem to be from the King James Bible, as so many such phrases are.

Answer (score 1):

Google ngram viewer shows the relative frequency of the three phrases:
[Google ngram viewer variants of bended/bent knee](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on%20bended%20knee%2Con%20a%20bended%20knee%2Con%20bended%20knees%2Con%20bent%20knee&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20bended%20knee%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20a%20bended%20knee%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20bended%20knees%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20bent%20knee%3B%2Cc0)

*On a bended knee* is pretty rare.
*On bended knee* and *on bended knees*
are seen to be about equally frequent until 1980, when the singular version became more common.

Also, the singular version has its own word:
[American Heritage Dictionary *genuflect*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=genuflect)

> 1. To bend the knee or touch one knee to the floor or ground, as in worship.

So, you don't have to bend both knees to show reverence.

Comment: 1) Can "bend one's knee" mean "bend both knees" as well as "bend one knee"? 2) And can "bend one's knees" mean the both? 3) And is "bend on A knee" grammatically incorrect?

Comment: *Bend one's knee*  in a figurative sense, doesn't involve any knee-counting. If it's literal, it means one knee. The plural, in a literal sense, means both. *Bend on a knee* doesn't make sense to me. Note that at the bottom of the page with the ngram viewer above, you can examine actual instances of the phrase in use. It would make more sense to discuss actual uses than to apply logic to what amount to fixed phrases.

Comment: But I am asking if it was literal. Would that idiom signify both positions and the same for the plural idiom?

Comment: If it's literal, *knee*  is one, and *knees* is more than one. I realize my answer may not have been clear - "the plural, in a literal sense, means both *knees*".

Comment: However, if you check free dictionary definitions of the idiom, you will find one of the definition says "lying on one or two knees"?

Comment: Sorry, "lying on knee/s" is just not idiomatic. You kneel on knees. You lie on your back or your belly or your side. You may need some other dictionaries.

Comment: Sorry I misquoted. Here you go: on bended knee -
On one's knee or knees, as in supplication or submission. What do you say?

Comment: It sounds as if it can be interpreted that way. I think that most uses of "on bended knee" are going to be figurative, though, so one vs. two won't matter.

Comment: I am so confused as to its more literal sense. Some dictionaries cites "on bended knee" as "on knee bent" and some  "one or both". I am confused.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130360/discussion-between-sudhanshu-kumar-and-jack-oflaherty).